# divide a dataframe into another dataframe (element by element)

Tags: python-polars

In pandas, I could set several named columns as an index and find the quotient of the division of two
DataFrame,like this

```
import pandas as pd

df_1=pd.DataFrame( {
    'Name':['a','a','a', 'b','b', 'c'],
    'Name_2':['first','second','third', 'first','second', 'first'],
    'Value':[20,40,50,100,150,400]

})
df_2=pd.DataFrame( {
    'Name':['a','a','a', 'b','b', 'c'],
    'Name_2':['first','second','third', 'first','second', 'first'],
    'Value':[10,20,25,50,75,200]

})
df_1=df_1.set_index(['Name','Name_2'])
df_2=df_2.set_index(['Name','Name_2'])
df_1/df_2
```

How can something like this be implemented in python-polars?

I can't find an answer to this question in the documentation.

Comment: Could you explain what this code does? What is it exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @ritchie46 I had to run their pandas code to figure it out but I think I got it answered.

Comment: element-wise division of two matrices...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use a join, then do the math on the appropriate column(s).

```
df_1=pl.DataFrame( {
    'Name':['a','a','a', 'b','b', 'c'],
    'Name_2':['first','second','third', 'first','second', 'first'],
    'Value':[20,40,50,100,150,400]

})
df_2=pl.DataFrame( {
    'Name':['a','a','a', 'b','b', 'c'],
    'Name_2':['first','second','third', 'first','second', 'first'],
    'Value':[10,20,25,50,75,200]

})
```

That's the setup then the solution is:

```
df_1.join(df_2, on=['Name','Name_2']) \
    .select(['Name','Name_2', pl.col('Value')/pl.col('Value_right')])
```

If you have a bunch of "Value" columns and different indx columns you can do something like:

```
myindxcols=['Name', 'Name_2]
myvalcols=[x for x in df_1.columns if x in df_2.columns and not x in myindxcols]
df_1.join(df_2, on=myindxcols) \
    .select(myindxcols + [pl.col(x)/pl.col(f"{x}_right") for x in myvalcols])
```

Answer (score 1):

@Dean MacGregor beat me to it. Please accept his answer.

```py
df_1 = pl.DataFrame( {
    "Name":["a","a","a", "b","b", "c"],
    "Name_2":["first","second","third", "first","second", "first"],
    "Value":[20,40,50,100,150,400]

})

df_2 = pl.DataFrame( {
    "Name":["a","a","a", "b","b", "c"],
    "Name_2":["first","second","third", "first","second", "first"],
    "Value":[10,20,25,50,75,200]
})

keys = ["Name", "Name_2"]

(df_1
 .join(df_2, on=keys, suffix="_right")
 .select([
     *keys,
     pl.col("Value") / pl.col("Value_right")
 ])
)
```

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌──────┬────────┬───────┐
│ Name ┆ Name_2 ┆ Value │
│ ---  ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ str  ┆ str    ┆ f64   │
╞══════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ a    ┆ first  ┆ 2.0   │
│ a    ┆ second ┆ 2.0   │
│ a    ┆ third  ┆ 2.0   │
│ b    ┆ first  ┆ 2.0   │
│ b    ┆ second ┆ 2.0   │
│ c    ┆ first  ┆ 2.0   │
└──────┴────────┴───────┘
```